# Where is the error in the use of polar coordinates to find the volume of a cone.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let the cone be opening along the $z$ axis and be of height $h$ and radius $a$.

Then the region of integration would be $\theta \in [0,2\pi],~ r\in[0,a],~ z \in[x^2+y^2=z^2,h]=[r,h]$ but this does not give the correct answer after doing the triple integral over the region?

Comment: Without seeing your work we can't find the error.  It certainly should give the right answer.

Comment: So this is the correct integral? $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{a}\int_{r}^{h} r dz dr d\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You have a mistake in the limits of integration for $z$. The correct limits are:
$$
\frac{h}{a}r\le z \le h
$$

You can found this simply using the similitude of triangles in a section of the cone.

the volume is
$$
V=\int_0^{2\pi}d \theta \int_0^a r dr \int_{\frac{h}{a}r}^hdz
$$

---

[image]

The figure is a section of the cone. By similitude of triangles we have:
$$z:h=r:a  \quad \rightarrow \quad z=\frac{h}{a}r$$

Comment: You can see this because the range in $z$ should be zero when $r=a$

Comment: I really don't see how that is the correct limits. Surely if we fix $r,\theta$ then $z$ is going to go from the the point where it first touches the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2 \implies z=\pm r$ all the way to the top of the cone at $z=h$?

Comment: @Emilio Novati Could you explain why this is the case?

Comment: I've added a figure. I hope it's useful :)

Comment: I still don't understand why my method is wrong and I don't understand what you mean sorry.

Comment: Could you explain why my thinking doesn't apply?

Comment: Look at the figure. The maximum value for $z$  is $h$, but the minimum value, for any given shell of radius $r$, is not $r$ but the height of the triangle that has basis $r$ and this is $z=hr/a$ by similitude with the great triangle with basis $a$ and height $h$.

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand never mind guess I am not able thanks anyway.